# what is the use of "https://expired.badssl.com" ? Can someone explain it to me

Tags: ssl-certificate, java-security

I am using it in my code as follow. but can't understand what is the use of it.

```java
URL url = new URL("https://expired.badssl.com/");//https://revoked.grc.com/
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(connection.getHostnameVerifier());
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(connection.getSSLContext().getSocketFactory();

LineNumberReader lnr = 
   new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

String line;
while (null != (line = lnr.readLine()))
   System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: Its a test URL to test https/ssl client implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> https://expired.badssl.com/
> ```

has expired SSL certificate, used to test edge cases where you may encounter expired certificate while connecting to some website.

You can find more @ https://github.com/chromium/badssl.com

It provides other sub-domains as

`self-signed.badssl.com` to test self signed certificate related edge cases

`mixed.badssl.com` etc.